# ODBC Data Source with Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, connection, odbc, datasource

I am trying to connect to a Primavera P6 Database hosted on my network with driver Oracle in OraDb11g_home1. I currently have readonly access via the frontend, which I can successfully navigate records this way.

However, every attempt I have made to connect with a DSN has failed. I'm assuming that if I can connect to the frontend (even if readonly) that I should be able to connect via DSN with the same credentials?

The farthest I have gotten leaves me with an invalid username/password error. Here are the connection details:

in `tnsnames.ora`:

```
CHPPRIPA.world =
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xamxilux002)(PORT = 1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SID = CHPPRIPA)
        )
)
```

I have similarly tried connecting using JDBC Driver (using a connection string) with the same username and password where

`driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"`

and

`db_url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ramxilux002)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=CHPPRIPA)))"`.

```
username = "csdba" # (Central Services Database Admin);Level 1 - P6 Client - View Only
```

I still get the same invalid username/password error.

Am I wrong in believing that the same credentials should get me the same access in both places? Anyone experience this problem?

Comment: So you are saying you can cannot with the same username/password with sqlplus and it works?

Comment: I can login via the front end interface they have set up on my network, but the same credentials don't get me in via the methods I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The user interface known as P6 Professional or P6 Web uses different login credentials than what you need to get into the database. Only the DBA can give you those credentials.

Additionally, I would like to ask why you feel you need access to the database. This will impact how you connect to the database and which schema to use.

The SID you are showing is not typical of the "stock" installer/upgrader for Oracle databases running Primavera P6.

There are FIVE schemas in the Primavera P6 database. It is strongly recommended that you not attach to any except the extended schema for reporting.